# Debugging NET Azure Functions project using an external terminal in VS code on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

The VS code Azure Functions extension automatically created a launch config for debugging my project locally.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works well. However, I'd like to use an external terminal to debug instead of the integrated one. According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#:%7E:text=console%20-%20what%20kind%20of%20console%20to%20use%2C%20for%20example%2C%20internalConsole%2C%20integratedTerminal%2C%20or%20externalTerminal) doc, there is an option for this case, but it does not work in my case. Still, this is supposed to work for others; but I'm told then the debugger must not `attach` to the process but instead `launch` it itself (*type* key in json). And I have not gotten this to work that way.

Do any of you have working debug config for the `Functions/VScode/ExternalTerminal/Win` combo?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro using this [Kenichiro Nakamura site](https://dev.to/kenakamu/debug-net-5-function-with-visual-studio-visual-studio-code-5235), got the same issue.

I have opened the external terminal and used the below commands to run the debug:

1. Creating a function in a new folder

```
mkdir debugmyfunction
cd debugmyfunction
func new -n debugtest --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated
```

2. There will be a list of triggers, I selected `HttpTrigger` and then run the command `func start`

[image]

3)
Set the breakpoint after the `Main() function` in the **program.cs**

As I'm using VS Code So after pressing F5, it asked me `AzureWebJobsStorage` is not configured, then I disabled it to `false` and run again.

or

Run this command by opening the another external terminal and moving to your project directory:

```
func start --dotnet-isolated-debug
```

By default, .Net Core is the process attached in my debug console.

Then it takes a bit of time and show the following
Output:
[image]